Why did they redraw the lines of the ward?
Tom Mulligan asks his son and politican Jack if opponent Jamal conceded, expressing concern about
losing to him. Jack reassures Tom, hinting that compromise could have avoided the situation,
referencing a disagreement with the mayor on a housing development. Tom insists on his independence,
refusing to yield to pressure:

Tom: He had his agenda, I had mine.
JACK: Look where that's got us. The lines of the ward are redrawn and
we're down 7,000 votes that would've gone our way.

Why did they redraw the lines of the ward?

Electoral boundaries are usually periodically redrawn to reflect population changes, in almost any country with an electoral system.
Depending on the laws of the locality, independent boundary officials or politicians have more or less control of the process.  It sounds that in Widows, the Mayor has some power over the process and because of the dispute with Tom the new boundaries that were adopted were not as favorable to him.
So the short answer is that boundaries are redrawn to reflect population changes, but boundary decisions are not a precise science and how this is done can be beneficial or detrimental to individual politicians.

For more information on how this is done with explicit political intentions see Gerrymandering.
